# Java - How to see the update of an ArrayList in realtime?

Tags: java, arraylist, jbutton

For my school project, I need to see the update of an ArrayList in real time.

Now I'm using a JOptionPane that it allows me to insert a data in this ArrayList. The data in that list are "read" and added in a JButton form in a JPanel.

```
    addGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(percorsoDatabase);
                stmt = conn.createStatement();

                String nGame =  popGame.showInputDialog("Add new Game");

                game = "INSERT INTO Game (nGame)VALUES ('"+nGame+"');";

                stmt.execute(game);

                System.out.println("Game added in the Database");


            } catch (SQLException ex){
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

And my code for the JButtons displayed is the following:

```
    for (Game g: games){
        listGamePane.add(g.getButton());
    }
```

My problem is that my last data appear only when I re-run my program (close and start again), the JButton is added only if I execute that action. How can I see the JButton appear just after the "ok" of the JOptionPane without re-running anything?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

Comment: Do you re-read your data after you insert a new one?

Comment: Nope, I read them only when my program is launched read the data. How can I do that? Should I recall the statement of the JButton in the try/catch or after them?

Comment: So that's where your problem is. As soon you insert/save data, retrieve the data again(same as reading data when you launch) and re-render your button with the newly read data.